# Why execution of this block never ends?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Suppose we have a package PACK

```
package PACK is procedure DO; end PACK;

package body PACK is       
        procedure DO is begin DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello from PACK'); end;
end PACK;
```

Why does execution of the block

```
begin
    PACK.do;
    execute immediate 'alter package PACK compile';
end;
```

never end (session seems to be hanging)? However, separate execution of the first and the second line (in different anonymous blocks) is successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is been in use, that means an `instance` of it is still active. So, unless it is been killed, you cannot alter its state.

When a procedure or any stored function is been invoked, a locked is acquired by that session over that object state. Unless the caller completes the module, the lock remain active.

In your case, you are trying to alter the package within same PL/SQL block which called it. It results with `deadlock`. The `PL/SQL` block trying to dynamically execute your DDL, but there's lock already in place, when the package is first called!

> Please note that same PL/SQL can still call the package after this
>   dynamic DDL (It can be `DROP` too!). So for consistency sake, the lock
>   is not released unless the entire PL/SQL is been completed!

```
ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object ..
```

Where-as ,when you call in a **separate** `PL/SQL` block, the lock would already be released. Before the DDL is invoked.

Trying running this SQL in a different session.

```
select * from v$access where object = 'PACK';
```